# Nested trait types, bounded types and verbosity in use of the as keyword

Tags: rust, traits

I have question regarding the use the  readability and verbosity of the **as** keyword for nested types within traits.

I'm coming from a C++ background and I suspect that my misunderstanding will come from a lack of knowledge of the type systems used Haskell, which I understand rust makes use of.

In C++, templated structs are used as traits, where types are defined based on the template parameters. Nesting can occur where other struct types are defined within structs etc. etc.

Rust seems to support similar functionality. `struct MyStruct<F: Foo>` which is part of a larger code snippet below, defines members based on the types in supplied type `F`, bounded to trait `Foo`:

```
struct MyStruct<F: Foo>  {
// Why does this not work?
// Surely F, being constrainted to a Foo,
//   has a type BAR, constrained to Bar<F>,
//   has a type BAZ, constrained to Baz<F>
//        data: Vec<F::BAR::BAZ>,
    data: Vec< <<F as Foo>::BAR as Bar<F>>::BAZ >,
}
```

Briefly, when defining members in this struct, it seems one has to use `<<F as Foo>::BAR as Bar<F>>::BAZ` to provide the compiler with extra type information. This seems reasonable since the compiler must know about the type of `F` in order to reason about its types. However it seems to me that this information is already provided by the bounds placed on these types, within the generic parameter to the struct, and within the trait definitions themselves.

I do find `<<F as Foo>::BAR as Bar<F>>::BAZ` a bit difficult to read compared to `F::BAR::BAZ` and I was wondering if there was anyway to handle this better from a code readability point of view? Full code snippet below:

```
use std::vec::{Vec};

pub trait Foo {
    type VALUE;
    type BAR: Bar<Self>;
}

pub trait Bar<F: Foo> {
    type BAZ: Baz<F>;    
}

pub trait Baz<F: Foo> {
    fn new(value: F::VALUE) -> Box<F::VALUE> {
        Box::new(value)
    }
}

fn main() {
    struct BarImpl;

    impl<F: Foo> Bar<F> for BarImpl {
        type BAZ = BazImpl;
    }

    struct FooImpl;

    impl Foo for FooImpl {
        type VALUE = f64;
        type BAR = BarImpl;
    }

    struct BazImpl { dummy: i32 };

    impl<F: Foo> Baz<F> for BazImpl {};


    struct MyStruct<F: Foo>  {
    // Why does this not work?
    // Surely F, being constrainted to a Foo,
    //   has a type BAR, constrained to Bar<F>,
    //   has a type BAZ, constrained to Baz<F>
    //        data: Vec<F::BAR::BAZ>,
        data: Vec< <<F as Foo>::BAR as Bar<F>>::BAZ >,
    }

    let mut s = MyStruct::<FooImpl> { data: Vec::new() };

    for x in 0..5 {
        let b = BazImpl{ dummy: x};
        s.data.push(b);
    }

    println!("s.data.len() = {}", s.data.len());
}
```

Comment: Convention for associated types is camel case, i.e. `Value`, not `VALUE`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Thanks will use in future, I think I used it in this case to distinguish the types from the Traits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first level can be implied, so you can have `Vec<<F::BAR as Bar<F>>::BAZ>`. It’s quite possible that in the future the rules will be loosened up so that it can cope with inferring appropriate constraints for multiple levels, but it’s not the case now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [type alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/type-aliases.html)

```
type FooBarBaz<F> = <<F as Foo>::BAR as Bar<F>>::BAZ;

struct MyStruct<F: Foo>  {
    data: Vec< FooBarBaz<F> >,
}
```